# Magento 1.9 How to display subcategory image in top navigation menu

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to magento and I need a little help in displaying the image from the subcategory. I have uploaded a image in subcategory from my magento back-end.

Answer (score 0):

***I think, you will be helpful below code***

```
$categoryObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$categoryObj->getName() -- This display category Name
$categoryObj->getImageUrl() -- This display category Image
```

Let me know if face any issue